# joining multiple table in ms sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

[![expected result that i want
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrYtD.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrYtD.png)

```
select 
bd.BuildingID , 
bd.[Building Description] , 
fl.Floor , 
rm.Room,
rm.[Room Description],
rm.[Room Type],
asse.AssetName,
cmp.ComponentName
from Buildings bd 
join Floors fl
on bd.BLDID = fl.BLDID
join Rooms rm
on fl.FLID = rm.FLID
join Assets asse 
join Components cmp
on cmp.AssetID=asse.AssetID;
```

I am trying to join multiple tables in ms sql server.
I have 5 tables:

1. buildings
2. floors
3. rooms
4. assets
5. components

I want records from multiple tables.

- I joined `bd.BLDID = fl.BLDID` as I want `bd.BuildingID` and 
  `bd.[Building Description]` and both of them have common `BLID`.
- I joined `fl.FLID = rm.FLID` as I want `rm.Room`, `rm.[Room Description]`, and `rm.[Room_Type]`
- I want to join asset and components as well as I want `asse.AssetName` and
  `cmp.ComponentName` (both tables have a common `AssetID`)

I know the query above won't work because of the last 2 lines.

Can anyone suggest how this join could be accomplished?

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44730998/edit) your question and add sample data and expected resaults?

Comment: On what field can Assets be joined to one of the other tables? Does it have a ROOMID or something like that? In that case, you should add that after "join Assets asse".

Comment: @Bartez assets can be join with other table (Components ) using AssetID as both of them have common this field.

Answer (score 0):

Per comments, we'd need to know which fields were available in your database to fully answer your question.

At a guess, I'd say assets are likely held in a room, so there's likely to be a `RoomId` value (or `RMID` given the naming convention that seems to be in place) on the assets.

If that's the case, something like this should work:

```sql
select bd.BuildingID 
, bd.[Building Description] 
, fl.Floor 
, rm.Room
, rm.[Room Description]
, rm.[Room Type]
, asse.AssetName
, cmp.ComponentName
from Buildings bd 
inner join Floors fl
on bd.BLDID = fl.BLDID
inner join Rooms rm
on fl.FLID = rm.FLID
inner join Assets asse

on asse.RMID = rm.RMID --added this line

inner join Components cmp
on cmp.AssetID=asse.AssetID;
```

Comment: sir john : asset don't have RMID its have only asset id that i want to match with components table ,, because within components we have asset id as will.

Comment: @SalmanAbdulKarim what other columns does the `Assets` table have?  It will have more columns than just an ID / joining it to the `Rooms` table would have no impact on the join with the `Components` table.

Comment: If you're unsure, please can you run the below SQL & add the results to your question; this should help us learn more about your table structure / will hopefully enable us to answer your question.
`select t.name, c.name
from sys.tables t
inner join sys.columns c
on c.object_id = t.object_id
where t.name in ('Buildings','Floors','Rooms','Assets')
order by t.name, c.name`

Comment: dear sir john : i added the pic plz check it

Comment: I can't see it; the only image visible is your desired output; not the results of the above query.